# Adding "Active" Class to current post ancestor menu item parent in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-nav-menu-item

I have a menu like this in wordpress

- Parent Item ( A Page )

  - Child Item ( A Category )

When I am in the **Child Item** (category) page **"current-menu-parent"** class is added to the **"Parent Item"** , that is quite useful. But When I view one of the post from **Child Item** ( Category ) no special class is added to **"Parent Item"** . Only **"current-post-ancestor"** class is added to **Child Item** ( Category ) . How can I add a class to **"Parent Item"** when I am viewing a post from **Child Item** ( category ) ?

**Note** : I want a PHP solution , Javascript/Jquery solution is not accepted .

**Update :**

This is what I have so far. But it is adding class to all of the parent item which has child.

```
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_parent_class' );
function add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {
$parents = array();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->current_item_ancestor) {
        $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
    }
}

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
        $item->classes[] = 'active'; 
    }
}

return $items;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything for yourself?

Comment: Yea.. I have updated the question with what I have tried so far..

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer of my own question this is what I was looking for ..

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_parent_class' );
function add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {

$parents = array();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( in_array('current-post-ancestor', $item->classes)  ) {
        $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
    }
}

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
        $item->classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor'; 
    }
}

return $items;    
}
```

It will add a class to **current post ancestor** menu item parent.